# nestjs what is the best way to handle repeated user exception?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, nestjs

I'm a front-end developer who starts nest for my small project backend.
I'm trying to write a user signup module and I want to check my MongoDB to see if we already have a user with current PhoneNumber in our DB or not.

```
async addUser(createUserDTO: CreateUserDTO): Promise<IUser> {
    const UserWithSamePhoneNumberList: IUser[] = await 
    this.findUserByPhoneNumber(createUserDTO.phoneNumber);
    if(UserWithSamePhoneNumberList.length > 0) {
        console.log("repeative phone number");
    }
    const hash:string = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDTO.password, this.saltRounds);
    const userDTo: CreateUserDTO = {
        name: createUserDTO.name,
        password: hash,
        phoneNumber: createUserDTO.phoneNumber,
        signupDate: new Date().toString()
    };
    const newUser: any = new this.userModel(userDTo);
    return newUser.save();
}
async findUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber:string): Promise<IUser[]> {
    return this.userModel.find({phoneNumber:phoneNumber});
}
```

i write the code and it log the `repeative phone number` successfully but my problem is i dont know what is the standard way to throw exception of repeative phonenumber and send standard response to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply throw the exception, nest will attach proper status code automatically

```
    if(UserWithSamePhoneNumberList.length > 0) {
    throw new ConflictException({errorObject})   
 }
```

Comment: `throw new     throw new ConflictException({statusCode: HttpStatus.Cobnflict, message: 'repetive phone number'})   
`